# Sidekiq will execute your job at least once, not exactly once

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

I came across Sidekiq [best practices docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional) mentioning that

> Just remember that Sidekiq will execute your job at least once, not
> exactly once.

Can anyone explain what does that mean with examples?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of `at least once` at the beginning of this [paragraph](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional).

> For instance, with the error retry functionality, your job might be half-processed, throw an error, and then be re-executed over and over until it successfully completes.

```rb
def perform 
  $counter += 1 
  raise RuntimeError, 'Run again'
end
```

As shown above, we raise an error before successfully completes, this job will be retried until the number of tries exhausted. Every time the job runs, `$counter` will increase by 1.
Make your job idempotent and transactional to avoid inconsistencies.